# Show directory tree for matching directory names

Tags: linux, bash, tree-view

I know that `tree` allows for pattern matching, but that only works for files inside directories. Let's say i have a folder structure looking like that:

```
➜  test tree
.
├── testdir1
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── testdir2
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── testdir3
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── testdir4
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── testdir5
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── thatdir
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
└── thatdir2
    ├── file1
    └── file2
```

And i want tree to only display contents of folders starting with `that`  displayed in tree. I put together a bootleg zsh script that does what i needed:

`for i in that*; tree $i;`

output:

```
➜  test for i in that*; tree $i;
thatdir
├── file1
└── file2

0 directories, 2 files
thatdir2
├── file1
└── file2
```

However, I wondered if there is a better way of doing that instead of mindlessly putting a script over something instead of properly utilizing the tool (Also the formatting is a bit broken since command is executed multiple times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tree that*` should do what you want and is simpler

Comment: Honestly i'm an idiot

Comment: @w1kl4s  )  no we'd rather say "less experienced user" as per local standard of conduct. Frankly there are a lot of areas where I feel exactly the same

Comment: "Failure is the key to success; each mistake teaches us something." - said someone, at some point in time...